# nodejs npm libraries to access and modify microsoft word documents

Tags: pdf, npm, ms-word, docx

Do you know if it is possible to search specific text like "xAx" into a Microsoft Word file (.doc or .docx) hosted on a website, replace it with some other text input by the user and make the file available for download using nodejs?

Is there a npm library that can do that?

If not it is possible to manipulate a PDF file instead? Please note that I do not want to create the document but manipulate a template file in the server.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a project https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater which serves for replacing `placeholders` in .docx files.

Also supports loops and images, check out following demos :

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#image-replacement

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#image

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you so much!

Comment: Unbelievable!! I was going to create the whole document from scratch. You saved my life!!.

Comment: But images support in that library is not free

Comment: Yes, image support is not open source.

Answer (score -1):

If odt is an option (these files are open directly by MS Word besides Open and Libre Office and can be set with extension .doc so end users do not freak out) you can use [HTML52PDF](http://www.html52pdf.com/user-guide/replace-template-content).

For example something like the following code will replace a string of text by a link:

```
require_once 'path/to/CreateDocument.inc';
$doc = new Html52pdf\createDocument(array('template' => 'template.odt'));
$format = '.odt';//.pdf, .doc, .docx, .odt, .rtf
//replace natural text
$doc->replace(array('replace me, please' => array('value' => '<a href="http://www.html52pdf.com">external link</a>')), array('format' => array('','')));

$doc->render('replaced_content' . $format);
```

Comment: this is not a nodejs solution like the question requested