# Edit word document and replace text and image placeholders dynamically with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-word, docx

Is there a way where I can read a word file (.docx) via Node JS which has placeholders like `{text1} / {image1}` and replace those with the real ones.  I have tried couple of npm modules where in I was able to create a fresh copy of docx but unable to edit or replace image and text.  Thanks in anticipation for the help.

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristianBaumann - I am aware.  But the thing is I couldn't find a way to edit the word.  Also I have mentioned the tried npm modules doesn't help to edit the docx and replace images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs npm libraries to access and modify microsoft word documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996641/nodejs-npm-libraries-to-access-and-modify-microsoft-word-documents)

Answer (score 13):

There is a project https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater which serves for replacing `placeholders` in .docx files.

Also supports loops and images, check out following demos :

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#image-replacement

https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#image

Source : Refer this [nodejs npm libraries to access and modify microsoft word documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996641/nodejs-npm-libraries-to-access-and-modify-microsoft-word-documents#answer-33497602)

Comment: Docxtemplater has lots off issue

Comment: What issue do you still see in Docxtemplater ? I'm the maintainer and creator of docxtemplater.

Comment: Price of modules seems to be an issue for homemade solutions. :D 
Wanted to use your package to create simple docx file. One of the needs is to create a table, but I just noticed it's 500E/year per module. I guess your target is enterprise. Good luck!
I will switch to another docx library or will create template in LaTeX instead. In the very end I need to compile to pdf anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Open source docx templates library:
https://github.com/guigrpa/docx-templates
A lot of templating functionalities for docx documents. I just used it yesterday for the first time and was able to quickly achieve desired solution.  Including simple tag templates, but also more complicated table template.

Answer (score 0):

You need "Patcher" from npm lib "docx"  ([doc](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/patcher?id=how-to-patch-existing-document)).

The simple code example bellow

```html
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {
  Paragraph,
  patchDocument,
  PatchType,
} from 'docx';

const editDocx = async () => {
  try {
    const doc = await patchDocument(fs.readFileSync('TestTemplate.docx'), {
      patches: {
        my_tag_here: {
          type: PatchType.DOCUMENT,
          children: [
            new Paragraph({text: 'Replaced text'}),
          ],
        },
      },
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('Result.docx', doc);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
  }
};

editDocx()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Document edited successfully.');
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(`Failed to edit document: ${error}`);
});
```

[image: TestTemplate.docx]
[image: Result.docx]